# Can't set text and segmentedCtrl in UINavigationBar

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, uinavigationbar

I try to call UINavigationBar @ main page. It shows navigationbar but without text and segmented controll. I dont know why it doesn't show. Please help me why and how I fix it.

Here is code

@MainController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NavigationBar = [[BINavigationBar alloc] init];

    [self.view addSubview:[NavigationBar getNavigationbar:@"Desktop"]];
}
```

@BINavigationBar.m

```
-(UINavigationBar *)getNavigationbar:(NSString *)name
{
    navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 44)];
    //UILabel *namelb = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    //namelb.text = @"DesktopTest";
    //[navigationBar.topItem.titleView addSubview:namelb];
    navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Desktop";

    UIBarButtonItem *segmentBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[self getSegmentedControl]];
    navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem = segmentBarItem;

    return navigationBar;
}

-(UISegmentedControl *)getSegmentedControl
{
    UISegmentedControl *segmented = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Archieve", @"Desktop", @"Library", nil]];
    segmented.frame = CGRectMake(0, 2, 120, 40);
    segmented.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;


    return segmented;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the title, just use:

```
navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Title"
```